# dexie cascating WhereClause

Tags: indexeddb, dexie

Is it possible to cascade Dexie "WhereClause"?

Example: I want use

```
db.City.where("Name").startsWithAnyOfIgnoreCase(param1)
                     .orderBy("Name")?
```

but all methods in WhereClause object returns "Collection" which only provides filter to add more filters

Answer (score 0):

Your example only illustrated one WHERE condition. But it sounds like you are asking how to have multiple WHERE conditions during a single Table select. If so, I think you can find your answer in the (very well written) Dexie documentation here: http://dexie.org/docs/Table/Table.where()

The relevant code snippet is this:

```
db.friends.where(["name", "age"])
  .between(["David", 23], ["David", 43], true, true)
  .each(friend => {
      console.log("Found David, 43: " + JSON.stringify(friend));
  }).catch(error => {
      console.error(error.stack || error);
  });
```

Hope that answers your question.
F